# Showing how many records were updated by an update query

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to get a report of the records that are updated using a update query, without using a recordset?

Ex:

`sqltext = update table employees set bonus = 0 where salary > 50000

DoCmd.RunSQL sqltext`

After this query runs, is it possible to get the name of the employees for whom this update query was performed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use `DoCmd.RunSQL` as it generates a prompt (which you have to turn off if you don't want it), and it completes the updates even if errors occur, and doesn't report the errors. Much better is to replace it with a function that executes the same SQL:

```
Public Function SQLRun(strSQL As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo errHandler

  CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  SQLRun= True

exitRoutine:
  Exit Function

errHandler:
  MsgBox err.Number & ": " & err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in SQLRun()"
  Resume exitRoutine
End Function
```

Once you've placed this in a public module, you can easily do a global search and replace for `DoCmd.RunSQL` to replace it with `SQLRun`.

EDIT: Another version of this function that returns the number of records affected is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343396/acess-vba-to-get-value-from-update-query-prompt/348453#348453).

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old question, but there was no answer that directly answered the OP question (I got here via Google Top 3 results while trying to remember the syntax)
If you use the Execute method, you can get the number of records affected directly:

```
sqltext = "update table employees set bonus = 0 where salary > 50000"
CurrentDb.Execute sqltext
AffectedRows = CurrentDb.RecordsAffected
'Optional Notification
   MsgBox CStr(AffectedRows) & " records were affected by this SQL statement."
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way at this time to get the information after the update query has run unless you have another distinguishing field (maybe an updated date field).  Why not run a select query for it and run a report off of that data, THEN run the update query to change the values for 'bonus'.

Let me know if this helps!
JFV

Comment: i am not sure about this method as there are chances updates on certain records may fail to haapen but they may be picked up by the select query

Comment: As long as the data is not highly volatile, the 'Select' and the 'Update' should return the same records.  If the 'Update' fails, then you might have some other issues with the data.

Comment: You can open the Access database for exclusive access to run the select and update, just to make sure nobody got in and changed data on you between queries.