# Access vba: How to turn of systems messages or prompts?

Tags: ms-access

I use a form to run a few codes on a database in Access. During update or deletion Access asks whether you want to update or delete.

I would like to know if there is any way of turning off these system messages or let the user choose his preference on whether he would like thoses messages to pop up or not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't foget to turn these back on.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings false
DoCmd.SetWarnings true

Application.DisplayAlerts = false
Application.DisplayAlerts = true
```

Comment: any way for the user to choose this

Comment: You could create a form so that the user could choose this option.  If you don't turn it back on, it can cause some serious issues.  "Whoops I accidentally deleted the table, but it normally asks me before I do that..."

Comment: If these update or deletes are being made programmatically from vba, just turn SetWarnings off, execute the query, turn SetWarnings on.

Comment: I would echo Jason Lepack and also mention that changing these warnings applies to every database on the PC, not just the one you are working on, so they are quite dangerous to meddle with.

Comment: hmmm any other ideas other than using this. I mean i am trying to automate the process and it is tiresome if 20 or 30 table are updated and each keeps asking do u want to update?

Comment: Generally it is best to use 
CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError 
for update queries. You can also get records affected if you do this.

Comment: I've posted a function to make it easy to use CurrentDB.Execute. The code is posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343396/acess-vba-to-get-value-from-update-query-prompt#348453 .