# MS Access VBA: How to delete a row from a table without warning message

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a statement below in Access VBA.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from sys_AAAA_AAAA where AAA='apple'"
```

But Access asks me to confirm with a message box.

[image]

As I will have to repeat this command many times. Is there a way of suppressing this warning message or giving a 'yes' with a statment?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access vba: How to turn of systems messages or prompts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377878/access-vba-how-to-turn-of-systems-messages-or-prompts)

Comment: or google for `docmd runsql suppress warning`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't touch the warnings. Just use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from sys_AAAA_AAAA where AAA='apple'"
```