# ms-access - how to automatically select yes in warning message boxes

Tags: sql, ms-access

in ms-access i am running a macro that runs several queries, during the execution of a query a message box appears

"you are about to run an update.......... are you sure you want to run this query ? "

how can i automatically select  for all such cases so that macro runs without human intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off temporary the warnings like this:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings = False
DoCmd.RunSQL ...
DoCmd.SetWarnings = True
```

Comment: This is bad advice as 1) you also need to add docmd.setwarnings = true to error handling; 2) running execute will give you much better errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally best to use Execute in such cases in order to trap errors:

```
Dim db As Database, qdf As QueryDef, strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Query17")
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Debug.Print qdf.RecordsAffected
```

Or

```
strSQL="UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField=10"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
```

Trapping errors with dbFailOnError and an error trap is more or less essential and there are a number of other useful aspects to the [`Execute Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177900.aspx)

Comment: Unless you need the recordsaffected value you don't need to define the db or qdf.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to write the code @Remou supplies every time you execute arbitrary SQL you could use [my SQLRun function, which is designed as a dropin replacement for DoCmd.RunSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647591/form-has-my-table-locked-down-tight-even-after-docmd-close/1647793#1647793) and avoids all the problems therewith.

Comment: @Remou: you're right -- it appears it was your code that I was referring to. Post corrected.