# Code not executing properly but no error appears to be raised

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao, jet

On 2 occasions recently, code essentially the same as below failed to execute properly.

During the same timeframe it would also has executed normally hundreds of times.

On the 2 occasions slip was printed but no record was added to the database and no error was reported to the user.

I cannot understand how this could be.

The computer on which the error occurred is networked via cabled network to a shared Jet database with about 8 computers on it.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1

BeginTrans
Dim RS as RecordSet
Dim strRS as string

strRS = "Select * from Blah"

Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(strRS)

RS.AddNew
RS.Fields("Date1").value =  Now
RS.Fields("OpID").value =  intOpId
RS.Update                              

PrintSlip Now, intOpId                 
CommitTrans

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler1:
Rollback
MsgBox "There has been an error"
```

They have recently upgraded their netword with new cabling and machines but I can't see any reason particularly why this might be the problem.

Comment: Can you include the code for PrintSlip? Is it possible that the code is raising an error down in that method, just after a print occurs? Do you ever see the MsgBox at all?

Comment: ... or there could be something wrong with `CommitTrans` code. Can we see it please?

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling, Hi Sorry for the delay.  The code included is vastly simplified but the printslip sub does not have an errorhandler so that the errorhandler in the calling code traps it.

Comment: @George The begintrans, committrans and rollback are all built-in methods of the dao dbengine, I don't have any internal code for them

Comment: @kjack What does `PrintSlip()` do after sending the print job? Anything that could be erroring out? Is it possible to successfully send a print job, but then raise an error inside of `PrintSlip()`, thereby causing the `Rollback` before a `CommitTrans` can occur?

Comment: @kjack is it possible there is a Rollback in PrintSlip? that would explain printing a slip, no update and no error. Can't say much without seeing PrintSlip code

Comment: Is there an error handler above this one? If the committrans has an error and the Rollback errors - maybe because of a borked database then what will happen?  Is this and Access db?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on an error being raised, you can use a [`QueryDef`](http://www.upsizing.co.uk/Art26_RecordSets.aspx) object to add your records, then test the `.RecordsAffected` property to see how many records were actually added.

Some details here:
[How can I get a value from the update query prompt in Access VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343396/how-can-i-get-a-value-from-the-update-query-prompt-in-access-vba)

To summarize:

1. Create an append query with two [parameters](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/parameter3.php), `[TheDate]`, and `[TheOpID]`
2. Run code that looks something like this:

:

```
Dim qdf As New QueryDef
Set qdf = DB.QueryDefs("qappMyCoolParameterQuery")
With qdf
    !TheDate = Now
    !TheOpID = intOpId
    .Execute
    If .RecordsAffected = 0 Then
        'Freak Out, alert user, etc
    End If
End With
```